# Snap and certbot, unknown command 'unset'

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to set up Let's Encrypt certificates on an ec2 instance for the first time and have run into an error which I cannot find a resolution for online. I'm using the [official certbox nginx guide](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/pip-nginx), and am at the step where I need to install the route53 dns plugin. However, when I run `sudo snap install certbot-dns-route53`, I get the following error:

> error: cannot perform the following tasks:
>
> - Run hook prepare-plug-plugin of snap "certbot" (run hook "prepare-plug-plugin": error: error running
>   snapctl: unknown command `unset'. Please specify one command of: get, restart, set, start or stop)

The only solution I can find online that mentions this issue says to update snap. But snap has already been updated. Anyone familiar enough with snap and certbot on amzn2 to know what I can do here?

A bit more information:
This is running on an ec2 instance running Amazon's Linux 2 AMI (amzn2)
Output for `snap --version`:

```
snap   2.36.3-0.amzn2
snapd  2.36.3-0.amzn2
series 16
amzn   2
kernel 4.14.214-160.339.amzn2.x86_64
```

I have tried to update the core using the commands in the guide, `sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core` and it outputs:

> snap "core" has no updates available

Comment: Its kinda of hard to help without knowing more, like what linux distribution and version you're using. You might consider updating your question with that info.  That being said, my gut says that you need to update your version of snap.  Getting an error about snapctl not understanding "unset" just sounds like you have a version of snap that doesn't understand the command "unset"

Comment: @NicholasRees Added more details, such as the versions of snap and the distro I'm using. amzn2 is supposed to be based off of RHEL, but I'm not too sure. I'm not married to it, but it's what was recommended to me. 

As for the versions, I've provided them in the original question. They seem to be up to date to me, at least as far as the instance distro goes.

Comment: the latest stable snapd available from canonical is 2.48.2.1. https://snapcraft.io/snapd. Not sure why there would be a breaking change between 2.36 and 2.48, but that's still what my gut tells me to look at first.

Comment: Thanks, Nicholas. At work right now, will have a look at this when I get a chance.

Comment: I was able to fix this by uninstalling my version of snap and installing certbot via a guide I found specific to amzn2 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#install

To anyone encountering this in the future, consider a different distro that allows you to just follow the official certbot guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially installed snap (since it wasn't available simply via yum) following the instructions found [here](https://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Install_Snap_on_Amazon_Linux_Workspace). If you've done that and found this question, uninstall it.

Either switch your instance to a different distro or follow the install guide offered by Amazon [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#install). If you're using nginx, you can simply replace the reference of python2-certbot-apache with python-certbot-nginx. I stopped following after certbot was installed.